# UIAlertController private API usage?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, iphone-privateapi

Was the following code safe to use to create an `UIAlertController` :

```
   let titleFont:[String : AnyObject] = [ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 18)! ]
   let messageFont:[String : AnyObject] = [ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 14)! ]
   let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Multiple buttons", attributes: titleFont)
   let attributedMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Select an Action", attributes: messageFont)
   alert.setValue(attributedTitle, forKey: "attributedTitle")
   alert.setValue(attributedMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

I heard that setting TextAttributes to `UIAlertController` font was not safe to use and it touched private API.So, it might get rejected.

And [TutPlus+](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-alert-controller-in-ios-10-swift-3--cms-27589) posted tutorial like that. I just want to be sure. My above question doesn't mean anything to **TutPlus**. It was only a question about private APIs. I just want to be sure that if I use that code, will I get rejected or not.

Comment: Is your question will this get you rejected from the App Store?

Comment: yes...correct JAL

Comment: The answer is not only yes, but this is really unsafe from application maintenance point of view, as `UIAlertController` may not have the selectors `attributedTitle` or `attributedMessage` in the future, and your code would crash your app in that case.

Comment: Seconded with @JAL – if you absolutely must use another font, you'll be better off implementing your own custom `UIAlertController`, which is just a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: JAL & xoudini , when I tried that project in Xcode 8, it really worked without crashing anything. Actually I really wanted to develop UIAlertController same as iOS Alert Controller with custom fields. So, a little help?

Comment: @ThihaAung I recently wrote one for my company and I am fighting to get them to let me open source it at the moment. However there are plenty around, try [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/).

Comment: @ThihaAung It may work now, but as JAL stated, it may crash in the future. Your are using undocumented, private internal features. Apple can change those in a future iOS update and as a result, your code will start crashing.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who gives me best suggestions. An answer should be posted as well, so i can help you back again for giving time to me.

Comment: This important message on Apple developer site. =>
**The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**